# What is Prashtantrayi?

Tags: philosophy

I have heard this name many times related to Adi Shankaracharya. He has given many lectures about Prasthantrayi. Is this any Upanishad, Purana or else?

I just want to know some brief detail about Prasthantrayi.

Comment: See Wiki on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasthanatrayi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prasthana-traya are the basic source texts of Vedanta.

> The three basic texts of Vedanta are the Upanishads, the Bhagavad Gita
>   and the Brahma-sutra. Together they are referred to as the
>   prasthana-traya, triple canon of Vedanta. The Upanishads constitute
>   the revealed texts (Sruti-prasthana); they mark the summits of the
>   Veda which is Sruti (the heard, the revealed). They are the pristine
>   springs of Vedanta metaphysics; Vedanta is the name given to them
>   because they are the end (aim as well as concluding parts) of the Veda
>   (Veda + anta). The Bhagavad Gita comes next only to the Upanishads. It
>   is given a status which is almost equal to that of the Upanishads.
>   ....... As this text forms a part of the Mahabharata which is a Smriti
>   (the remembered, i.e., a secondary text based on the Veda), it is
>   called Smriti-prasthana. The third of the canonical texts is the
>   Brahma-sutra which is regarded as Nyaya-prasthana, becasue it sets
>   forth the teachings of Vedanta in a logical order.

T. M. P. Mahadevan's Foreward of Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Shankaracharya translated by Swami Gambhirananda